# iOS view positioning bug

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uiview, admob

I'm having a strange issue with positioning some content (in this case Admob ads) in my app. My views are standard `UITableViewControllers` and I want to position the ads so they are anchored to the very bottom of the view (above the toolbar though).

Here is the code I am using to place the ads (this is the delegate method required by the Admob SDK).

```
- (void)didReceiveAd:(AdMobView *)adView {
    // get the view frame
    //CGRect frame = self.navigationController.view.frame;
    CGRect frame = self.view.superview.frame;

    // put the ad at the bottom of the screen
    adMobAd.frame = CGRectMake(0, frame.size.height - 48, frame.size.width, 48);

    [self.view.superview addSubview:adMobAd];
}
```

This code works fine to initially place the ad, and the ad appears at the bottom of the screen where I want it.  However, there are times that the ad will jump to the middle of the screen after certain user interactions.

For instance, when a user selects and entry in the tableview and the next controller is loaded onto the navigation controller stack.  When the user navigates back to the initial tableview controller where the ad resides, the ad will now be in the middle of the screen instead of the bottom.

Or if the user selects a button that pops a new `modalViewController`, the same thing will happen when the `modalViewController` is dismissed.

Am I anchoring the ad to the wrong place?  Do I need to always reposition the ad when the view is loaded? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

What if you tried `CGRect frame = self.view.frame;` instead.

Are you hiding your navigationController at all? This could cause it to move up also

Comment: No, I'm not hiding the nav controller manually.  just via the presentModalViewController methods. Also, if I anchor it to self.view.frame it anchors it to the tableview not the main UIView which causes scrolling problems since I want it to always be locked to the bottom of the visible "viewport"